# Using Polymorphism instead of conditional statements PHP

Tags: php, polymorphism

I am practicing OOP concept in PHP. I’m developing a site to add products into mysql database.
Every product has its product_id, name, price and product_type.
3 types of products should be inserted (Laptop, TV and Speakers). And each type of products has different attributes.
Example,

```
Product id  : 1
Name        : DELL N5110
Price       : $2000
Product type : Laptop
CPU     : Intel Core i5
RAM     : 8GB DDR4
SSD     : 512GB

Product id  : 2
Name        : Samsung NU7100
Price       : $900
Product type : TV
Size        : 42 Inches

Product id  : 3
Name        : Creative SB1000
Price       : $90
Product Type : Speakers
Power       : 300w
Channels    : 2.1
```

I need to create individual class files for each product and insert data using Polymorphism instead of using conditional statements for handling differences in product types.
Do not use different endpoints for different products types. There should be 1 general endpoint for product saving

Comment: This specification is WAY beyond the scope of a single question. Given your primary objective is OOP, you should concentrate on that, leaving all storage related questions aside

Comment: Besides, I am afraid this is actually test/homework that doesn't show any effort. What are at least your thoughts on the possible solution?

Comment: And the recent edit just proves the point.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. As it stands, your question isn't suitable for SO yet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like below. The 'Product' class (parent) has all the 'base' properties and methods. In the 'Child' class you can extend with extra methods and properties for each producttype.

[image]

Comment: I need to create individual class files for each product and insert data using Polymorphism instead of using conditional statements for handling differences in product types.
Do not use different endpoints for different products types. There should be 1 general endpoint for product saving